# How to run a boot script on windows EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My question is how do you run a boot script on a windows EC2 (similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49594391/aws-ec2-run-script-program-at-startup) question but for windows rather than linux)

Also, does a 'stopped' instance being restarted count as a 'boot', or must the instance be terminated in order for the script to run. I ask because I would like the script to run whenever a lambda starts a *stopped* (not terminated) instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A script can be passed in the **User Data** property.

If you are using a Windows AMI, and the first line of the script begins with `<powershell>` or `<script>` (for normal DOS commands), then the script will be executed **the first time that the instance is started**.

For details, see: [Running Commands on Your Windows Instance at Launch - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-user-data.html)

Such a script **only runs the first time the instance is started**. More accurately, it is **only once per Instance ID**. This means that if you make an AMI of the instance, then any new instances launched from the AMI *will* run the User Data script.

If you wish a script to run *whenever the virtual machine is turned on*, then [use the capabilities of the operating system](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+run+on+startup). It has nothing to do with the fact that it is an Amazon EC2 instance.